# Merge several data.frames into one data.frame with a loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am trying to `merge` several `data.frames` into one `data.frame`. Since I have a whole list of files I am trying to do it with a loop structure.

So far the loop approach works fine. However, it looks pretty inefficient and I am wondering if there is a faster and easier approach.

Here is the scenario:
I have a directory with several `.csv` files. Each file contains the same identifier which can be used as the merger variable. Since the files are rather large in size I thought to read each file one at a time into R instead of reading all files at once.
So I get all the files of the directory with `list.files` and read in the first two files. Afterwards I use `merge` to get one `data.frame`.

```
FileNames <- list.files(path=".../tempDataFolder/")
FirstFile <- read.csv(file=paste(".../tempDataFolder/", FileNames[1], sep=""),
             header=T, na.strings="NULL")
SecondFile <- read.csv(file=paste(".../tempDataFolder/", FileNames[2], sep=""),
              header=T, na.strings="NULL")
dataMerge <- merge(FirstFile, SecondFile, by=c("COUNTRYNAME", "COUNTRYCODE", "Year"),
             all=T)
```

Now I use a `for` loop to get all the remaining `.csv` files and `merge` them into the already existing `data.frame`:

```
for(i in 3:length(FileNames)){ 
ReadInMerge <- read.csv(file=paste(".../tempDataFolder/", FileNames[i], sep=""),
               header=T, na.strings="NULL")
dataMerge <- merge(dataMerge, ReadInMerge, by=c("COUNTRYNAME", "COUNTRYCODE", "Year"),
             all=T)
}
```

Even though it works just fine I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to get the job done?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You may want to look at the closely [related question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562124/merge-many-data-frames-from-csv-files).

I would approach this in two steps: import all the data (with `plyr`), then merge it together:

```
filenames <- list.files(path=".../tempDataFolder/", full.names=TRUE)
library(plyr)
import.list <- llply(filenames, read.csv)
```

That will give you a list of all the files that you now need to merge together.  There are many ways to do this, but here's one approach (with `Reduce`):

```
data <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=T, 
    by=c("COUNTRYNAME", "COUNTRYCODE", "Year")), import.list, accumulate=F)
```

Alternatively, you can do this with the `reshape` package if you aren't comfortable with `Reduce`:

```
library(reshape)
data <- merge_recurse(import.list)
```

Comment: It may be worth noticing that you can get the whole thing merged, with an additional `.id` column containing filenames by calling `ldply` instead of `llply`. The `Reduce` or `merge` call is then unneeded.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, a pretty simple change could eliminate the `3:length(FileNames)` kludge:

```
FileNames <- list.files(path=".../tempDataFolder/", full.names=TRUE)
dataMerge <- data.frame()
for(f in FileNames){ 
  ReadInMerge <- read.csv(file=f, header=T, na.strings="NULL")
  dataMerge <- merge(dataMerge, ReadInMerge, 
               by=c("COUNTRYNAME", "COUNTRYCODE", "Year"), all=T)
}
```

Comment: @ken: since the `dataMerge` is an empty `data.frame` the `merge()` function cannot find an common identifier in the first `for` loop. if i assign eg the first file to `dataMerge` it kind of gets me back to my initial idea.

Comment: Sorry, I should have tried it first.  I was thinking of rbind(), in which an empty data frame is treated as if the required columns are present but empty.