# Recombining a list of Data.frames into a single data frame

Tags: list, r, dataframe

I am sorry if this question has been answered already. Also, this is my first time on stackoverflow.

I have a beginner R question concerning lists , data frames and `merge()` and/or `rbind()`.

I started with a Panel that looks like this

```
COUNTRY YEAR VAR
A         1
A         2
B         1
B         2
```

For efficiency purposes, I created a list that consists of one data frame for each country and performed a variety of calculations on each individual `data.frame`. However, I cannot seem to combine the individual data frames into one large frame again.

`rbind()` and `merge()` both tell me that only replacement of elements is allowed.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong/ and how to actually recombine the data frames?

Thank you

Answer (score 44):

Maybe you want to do something like:

`do.call("rbind", my.df.list)`

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns an error (I think because not all panels are balanced?) Either way, the above command worked. Thank you though.

Comment: That solution works, but it is slow

Answer (score 15):

dplyr lets you use bind_rows function for that:

```
library(dplyr)

foo <- list(df1 = data.frame(x=c('a', 'b', 'c'),y = c(1,2,3)), 
         df2 = data.frame(x=c('d', 'e', 'f'),y = c(4,5,6)))

bind_rows(foo)
```

Answer (score 10):

Note that the basic solution

```
do.call("rbind", my.df.list)
```

will be slow if we have many dataframes. A scalable solution is:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(my.df.list)
```

which, from the [docs](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/data.table/docs/rbindlist), is the `same as do.call("rbind", l) on data.frames, but much faster.`

Answer (score 4):

There might be a better way to do this, but this seems to work and it's straightforward. (My code has four lines so that it's easier to see the steps; these four could easily be combined.)

```
# first re-create your data frame:
A = matrix( ceiling(10*runif(8)), nrow=4)
colnames(A) = c("country", "year_var")
dfa = data.frame(A)

# now re-create the list you made from the individual rows of the data frame:
df1 = dfa[1,]
df2 = dfa[2,]
df3 = dfa[3,]
df4 = dfa[4,]
df_all = list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

# to recreate your original data frame:
x = unlist(df_all)         # from your list create a single 1D array 
A = matrix(x, nrow=4)      # dimension that array in accord w/ your original data frame
colnames(A) = c("country", "year_var")     # put the column names back on
dfa = data.frame(A)        # from the matrix, create your original data frame
```

Comment: Thank you for the script. It worked quite well, my only worry with this is that it doesn't automatically update if I were to add a country. (although I suppose with a for-loop I could do that, too)

Answer (score 4):

plyr is probably best. Another useful approach if the data frames can be different is to use reshape:

```
library(reshape)
data <- merge_recurse(listofdataframes)
```

Look at my answer to [this related question on merging data frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209258/merge-several-data-frames-into-one-data-frame-with-a-loop).

Comment: Do you have any idea why merge_recurse uses so much memory? I have 4 dataframes of 196 rows with one column, and it requires 6gb of memory