# rbind error: "names do not match previous names"

Tags: r, r-sp

As part of a larger problem (adding a `,makeUniqueIDs` argument to `rbind.SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` for situations when the polygon IDs are identical), I'm running into this weird message from rbind:

```
> do.call("rbind",xd.small)
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```

- [xd.small `dput` output](https://gist.github.com/3387091)

The only other info I could find on this was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504543/merge-multiple-data-frames-error-in-match-namesclabs-namesxi-names-do-n), which leads me to believe that `rbind` was at the root of the problem there also.

I can just write my own rbind-like function of course, but presumably this `match.names` check occurs for a reason, and I'm curious what it is.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The names (column names) of the first dataframe do not match the names of the second one. Just as the error message says.

```
> identical(names(xd.small[[1]]), names(xd.small[[2]]) )
[1] FALSE
```

If you do not care about the names of the 3rd or 4th columns of the second df, you can coerce them to be the same:

```
> names(xd.small[[1]]) <- names(xd.small[[2]]) 
> identical(names(xd.small[[1]]), names(xd.small[[2]]) )
[1] TRUE
```

Then things should proceed happily.

Comment: D'oh.  I'd checked them by eye with `lapply(xd,names)` but didn't notice the numbers were different.

Comment: maybe the `smartbind` from `gtools` package could be useful.

Comment: @TylerRinker That's a cool function.  I'll file it away for future use, but for this I'd rather stay with base R.

Comment: I didn't notice the subtle differences the first time I looked either, and wondered if there were some non-printing character that snuck in past dput.

Comment: `rbind.fill` from `plyr` is faster than `smartbind`

Comment: I'm getting this error with the identical test = TRUE

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. I just repeated my process and I get the same results as I did 4 years ago.

Comment: Very clean answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 44):

easy enough to use the `unname()` function:

```
data.frame <- unname(data.frame)
```

Comment: I believe rbind() actually requires the columns to have names. `rbind(unname(df[, 1:2]), unname(df[, 3:4]))` results in an `Error in if (facCol[jj]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` error for me.

Answer (score 3):

`rbind()` needs the two object names to be the same. For example, the first object names: `ID Age`, the next object names: `ID  Gender`,if you want to use `rbind()`, it will print out:

> names do not match previous names

Answer (score 2):

Use code as follows:

```
mylist <- lapply(pressure, function(i)read.xlsx(i,colNames = FALSE))#
mydata <- do.call('rbind',mylist)#
```