# Column names shift to left on read.table or read.csv

Tags: r, data-analysis, read.table, read.csv

Originally I have this TSV file (sample):

```
name   type   qty   
cxfm   1C     0
d2     H50    2
g3g    1G     2
hb     E37    1
nlx    E45    4
```

so I am using read.csv to read data from a .tsv file but I always get this output:

```
name   type   qty   
1      cxfm   1C     0
2      d2     H50    2
3      g3g    1G     2
4      hb     E37    1
5      nlx    E45    4
```

instead of getting this one:

```
       name   type   qty   
1      cxfm   1C     0
2      d2     H50    2
3      g3g    1G     2
4      hb     E37    1
5      nlx    E45    4
```

Any ideas this? this is what I am using to read the files:

```
    file_list<-list.files()

for (file in file_list){

  if (!exists("dataset")){
    dataset <- read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", row.names = NULL, blank.lines.skip = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
    names(dataset) <- c("rowID", names(dataset)[1:ncol(dataset)-1])
    }

  if (exists("dataset")){
    temp_dataset <- read.table(file, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", row.names = NULL, blank.lines.skip = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
    names(temp_dataset) <- c("rowID", names(temp_dataset)[1:ncol(temp_dataset)-1])
    dataset <- rbind(dataset, temp_dataset)
    rm(temp_dataset)
  }

}

dataset <- unique(dataset)

write.table(dataset, file = "dataset.tsv", sep = "\t")
```

Comment: have you tried `row.names=False`?

Comment: @Erin I thought of suggesting this, but perhaps he wants to keep the row names.

Comment: Oh, right! Actually I think row.names=1 might do the trick. That would tell R that the first element of the header corresponds to the second column in the csv...

Comment: I put row.names = NULL because I have duplicate values in my first column (to avoid getting this error: `duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I had to do to Fix it: set row.names to FALSE

```
write.table(dataset, file = "data.tsv", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: This is the direct answer to the original question.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be a missing column header in your source CSV file.  One option here would be to leave your `read.csv()` call as it is and simply adjust the names of the resulting data frame:

```
df <- read.csv(file,
               header = TRUE,
               sep = "\t",
               row.names = NULL,
               blank.lines.skip = TRUE,
               fill = TRUE,
               comment.char = "",
               quote = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

names(df) <- c("rowID", names(df)[1:ncol(df)-1])
```

Comment: I did that and now I have this error `Error in names(dataset) <- c("rowID", names(dataset)) :  'names' attribute [13] must be the same length as the vector [12]`

Comment: Sorry, use this: `names(df) <- c("rowID", names(df)[1:ncol(df)-1])`

Comment: thank you so much but now I have this ` Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names `

Comment: Then you must have some other problem in your R script.  If you post the relevant code I might be able to help.

Comment: Put this code in your question, not as a comment.  What do you plan to do with each `dataset` data frame after reading it from file?  This code snippet shows that you are overwriting each one, which doesn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: I am sorry I am still new to stackoverflow, for now i am just merging my tsv files and afterwords I am going to merge the one dataset file of each folder together based on 4 commun columns that ways I have one commun Data Source to work with in my java program ( and I will have to add few calculated columns to the general Datasource later on too)

Comment: Your code actually looks OK.  Are you _certain_ that the column headers are the same in _every_ file?

Comment: Yes they are it is the same columns header affected for all files only the data is devided to files everytime we reach a certain number of lines.

Comment: I disagree with you.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019461/rbind-error-names-do-not-match-previous-names) for more information.

Comment: Here is a quick fix you can try.  Add `names(temp_dataset) <- names(dataset)` to the second `if` condition.

Comment: No it still doesn't take into concideration the last column :/ I don't know why :/

Comment: Do your files even have the same _number_ of columns?  Did you check that?

Comment: Yep I did, it is impossible for them not to have the same number of columns cause it is the same template everytime I just duplicate it and fill it with data again

Comment: I sent you an email with samples