# Transforming the data from wide format to long format

Tags: r

I've the data which looks like the following:

```
Var1    Var1234 Var234  Var123456   Var12345678
  A        26     19        23          19
  B        25     10        11          27
  C        21     19        21          11
  D        29     18        22          26
  E        16     27        11          10
```

The reason for putting the weird looking variable name is to show that variable length are not same. I want to convert this data into following shape:

```
Var1    Var_names   Values
 A       Var1234      26
 B       Var1234      25
 C       Var1234      21
 D       Var1234      29
 E       Var1234      16
 A       Var234       19
 B       Var234       10
 C       Var234       19
 D       Var234       18
 E       Var234       27
 A      Var123456     23
 B      Var123456     11
 C      Var123456     21
 D      Var123456     22
 E      Var123456     11
 A      Var12345678   19
 B      Var12345678   27
 C      Var12345678   11
 D      Var12345678   26
 E      Var12345678   10
```

I was trying the following code:

```
new_data <- reshape2::melt(old_data, id = "Var1")
```

But it's giving the following error:

```
Using var1 as id variables
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```

Reshape function used:

```
new_data <- reshape(old_data, direction ="long", varying = list(names(old_data)[2:ncol(old_data)]), v.names="Value", idvar = "Var1")
```

Error:

```
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = paste(d[, idvar], times[1L],  : 
  invalid 'row.names' length
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019461/rbind-error-names-do-not-match-previous-names) option, but it didn't help me.

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve the issue?

Thank you!

Comment: It is working for me based on the example showed.  Which version of R and reshape2 you are using?  My version is  reshape2_1.4.1  and R 3.3.0

Comment: @akrun: I'm using R 3.1.3 and reshape2_1.4.1.

Comment: @Procrastinatus Maximus: I actually tried reshape as well. I'm getting this error. I used melt multiple times. But never came across this issue.

Comment: Can you try it on a fresh R session?

Comment: Try a fresh start.

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus: I just did that...but same issue.

Comment: Strange. I never had this issue with `reshape2` in any of the R versions I used (which is all of them since 2.15).

Comment: @akrun and ProcrastinatusMaximus: It seems to work with data.table melt. Thanks for your suggestions.