# Writing a script for reading many .csv files with similar filenames

Tags: matlab, r

I have several .csv files with similar filenames except a numeric month (i.e. 03_data.csv, 04_data.csv, 05_data.csv, etc.) that I'd like to read into R.

I have two questions:

- Is there a function in R similar to
  MATLAB's varname and assignin that
  will let me create/declare a variable name
  within a function or loop that will allow me to 
  read the respective .csv file - i.e.
  03_data.csv into 03_data data.frame,
  etc.? I want to write a quick loop to
  do this because the filenames are
  similar.
- As an alternative, is it better to
  create one dataframe with the first
  file and then append the rest using a
  for loop? How would I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209258/merge-several-data-frames-into-one-data-frame-with-a-loop/2209371#2209371).  You can create the file names easily with a paste command:

```
file.names <- paste(sprintf("%02d",1:10), "_data.csv", sep="")
```

Once you have your file names (whether by creating them or by reading them from the directory as in the other question), you can import them quickly with an lapply:

```
import.list <- lapply(file.names, read.csv)
```

Lastly, to combine the list into one dataframe, the easiest approach is to use the `reshape` function below:

```
library(reshape)
data <- merge_recurse(import.list)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I combined pieces of yours and Dirk's suggestions and it worked fine. In this example above import.list <- etc. what is happening, is R reading all the files into a dataframe called import.list?

Answer (score 4):

It is also very easy to read the content of a directory including use of regular expressions to skip focus on certain names only, e.g.

```
filestoread <- list.files(someDir, pattern="\\.csv$", full.names=TRUE)
```

returns all (fully-formed, including full path) files in the given directory `someDir` that end on ".csv".  You can get fancier with better regular expressions which are documented in many places.

Once you have your list of files, it is straightforward to read them all using `apply` or `lapply` or a loop.