# Aggregate data from different files into data structure

Tags: r

I noticed I encounter this task quite often when programming in R, yet I don't think I implement it "pretty".

I get a list of file names, each containing a table or a simple vector. I want to read all the files into some construct (list of tables?) so I can later manipulate them in simple loops.

I know how to read each file into a table/vector, but I do not know how to put all these objects together in one structure (list?).

Anyway, I guess this is VERY routine so I'll be happy to hear about your tricks.

Comment: this really is a repeat question with the one Shane points out below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209258/merge-several-data-frames-into-one-data-frame-with-a-loop/2209371#2209371

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, without `plyr`:

```
filenames <- c("file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt")
mydata <- array(list(NULL))

for (i in 1:length(filenames))
    {
    mydata[[i]] <- read.table(filenames[i])
    }
```

Comment: but better to pre-allocate the list, and might as well use the filenames: mydata <- vector("list", length(filenames)); names(mydata) <- filenames; ... mydata[[filenames[i]]] <- read.table(filenames[i])

Comment: @mdsumner: What's the advantage of preallocating? Also, in this way you can put the `read.table` statement in a `tryCatch` instruction, so if file does not exist/is corrupted etc, you end up with a NULL in `mydata` which can then be checked against later in the script

Comment: it saves memory usage - otherwise the entire mydata list is recreated each time it is visited by an incremented [[i]]

Answer (score 3):

Do all the files have the same # of columns? If so, I think this should work to put them all into one dataframe.

```
library(plyr)
x <- c(FILENAMES)
df <- ldply(x, read.table, sep = "\t", header = T)
```

If they don't have all the same columns, then use `llply()` instead

Comment: That will work even if the files don't have the same number of columns.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at my answer here: [Merge several data.frames into one data.frame with a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209258/merge-several-data-frames-into-one-data-frame-with-a-loop/2209371#2209371).