# R - How to transform a list of lists to matrix with unique indexes

Tags: r, list

I have a list which looking like this

```
[[1]] 
     users V1
 1      28  3
 2      33  1
 3      35  4
 4     260  1

[[2]]
     users V1
 1      33  2
 2     260  1
 3     285 13
```

How can I create a table like this one using R?

```
     users    V1    V2
 1      28     3    NA
 2      33     1     2
 3      35     4    NA
 4     260    NA     1
 5     285    13    NA
```

Comment: Could this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227223/r-list-to-data-frame

Comment: This is probably some type of a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209258/merge-several-data-frames-into-one-data-frame-with-a-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
 Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='users', all=TRUE), lst)
 #   users V1.x V1.y
#1    28    3   NA
#2    33    1    2
#3    35    4   NA
#4   260    1    1
#5   285   NA   13
```

Another option would be to use `join_all` from `plyr`.  But, this requires the column names other than the one used in the `by=` to be named differently.

```
library(plyr)
nm1 <- make.names(sapply(lst, colnames)[-1,],unique=TRUE)
join_all(Map(function(x,y) {names(x)[-1] <- y; x}, lst, nm1),
                                      by='users', type='full')
#   users V1 V1.1
#1    28  3   NA
#2    33  1    2
#3    35  4   NA
#4   260  1    1
#5   285 NA   13
```

#### data

```
lst <- list(structure(list(users = c(28L, 33L, 35L, 260L), V1 = c(3L, 
1L, 4L, 1L)), .Names = c("users", "V1"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4")), structure(list(users = c(33L, 260L, 285L),
 V1 = c(2L,  1L, 13L)), .Names = c("users", "V1"), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do.call` with `merge` on your list.

```
l <- list(structure(list(users = c(28, 33, 35, 260), V1 = c(3, 1, 
    4, 1)), .Names = c("users", "V1"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(users = c(33, 260, 285), V1 = c(2, 1, 13)), .Names = c("users", 
    "V1"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"))

do.call(merge, c(l, list(all = TRUE, by = "users")))
#  users V1.x V1.y
#1    28    3   NA
#2    33    1    2
#3    35    4   NA
#4   260    1    1
#5   285   NA   13
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks, I hadn't noticed that