# Using reduce to Merge several csv files with more than one column as condition and different length

Tags: r

I am trying to create one data frame from 87 .cvs files using 3 columns in common in all the excel files. The columns in common are `Date` `CowID` `Time`, but the files contain several columns that are not common but need to be merged.  Each file has also a different length, so I guess the final `data.frame` will have lots of NAs.  I don't have problems reading the files. I found a code to do it using [Merge several data.frames into one data.frame with a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209258/merge-several-data-frames-into-one-data-frame-with-a-loop).

```
filenames <- list.files(path= "...\\data\\dat_merge", full.names=TRUE)
library(plyr)
import.list <- llply(filenames, read.csv)
data <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE, 
                                    by.x=c("Date", "CowID", "Time"),             
                                    by.y=c("Date", "CowID", "Time")),
                                    import.list, accumulate=F)`
```

However when I tried to merge the files using `reduce` I got the error:

> Error in fix.by(by.y, y): 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

I don't know if the problem is because one the column in common is date and it is a character like 11/24/2018.

I tried to use `x <- multimerge(my_data, all = TRUE, by=c("Date", "CowID", "Time"))` but it does not work either

Comment: `merge(...,by = c("Date", "CowID", "Time"))`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would solve it:
Use lapply to read in all the files, and extract only the wanted columns.
Then use do.call("rbind",) to merge the dataframes.

```
data=do.call("rbind",lapply(filenames,function(f){
        temp=read.csv(f)
        temp=temp[,c("Date", "CowID", "Time")]
        return(temp)
    }))
```