# How to consolidate multiple data series in R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm doing some statistical processing of experimental data using R.

I have multiple files, each one with identical structure. Each row of each file has measurements made at the same time, for different dates, so that the general structure is like this:

`time   C1   C2    C3 

19:00  200  10.0  30 

19:01  220  10.0  45 

...`

What I need is to create a file with a summary of the values of one column from multiple files, so I will have, for example, the average and stdev of C2 at each time, along consecutive days.

`time   avg    dev 

19:00  205.0  30.0 

19:01  220.0  10.0 

...`

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of questions in Stack Overflow that can help you out. Try searching with "[r] multiple files" (omit the quotes). The [r] limits the search to only questions tagged r.

[Here's a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562124/merge-many-data-frames-from-csv-files) that might get at what you are needing

and [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+multiple+files) of the search

Answer (score 2):

Create `Files`, a vector of file names assuming the file names are of the indicated form or otherwise. Then read these files in, lapplying `read.table` to each name and rbinding the results together giving `m` which contains all rows of all tables. Finally `aggregate` the `m` data frame.

```
Files <- Sys.glob("test_*.txt")
m <- do.call(rbind, lapply(Files, read.table, header = TRUE))
aggregate(m[-1], m[1], function(x) c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this seams to be the proper way to go. However, R complains that "'FUN' must always return a scalar". If I use aggregate(m[-1].m[1],function(x) c(mean=mean(x))) it does the average.

Comment: @pablochchacin, Upgrade R to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(plyr)    
# Combine all the data
    data=rbind(data1,data2,data3)

    # to get the mean
    ddply(data,.(time),numcolwise(mean))
    # to get the sd
    ddply(data,.(time),numcolwise(sd))

    # You can combine both statements above into a single call and put the output into a data frame
    resulting_data=data.frame(ddply(data,.(time),numcolwise(mean)),ddply(data,.(time),numcolwise(sd))[,-1])

    # depending on the number of columns you have, name the output accordingly. For your example
    names(resulting_data)c=('time','C1'..)
```