# How to merge multiple data sets and append comments to a new variable

Tags: r, merge, dataset, text-processing

I have multiple data sets (hundreds) with time series data like this:

```
"File name";"18%MC001.TXT";"V 1.24"
"Title comment";"231020124070"
"Trigger Time";"'13-04-05 13:53:51"
"Ch";"A 1- 1";"A 1- 2";"A 1- 3";"A 1- 4";"A 1- 5";"A 1- 6";"A 1- 7";"A 1- 8";"A 1- 9";"A 1-10";"A 1-11";"A 1-12";"A 1-13";"A 1-14";"A 1-15";"A 2- 1";"A 2- 2";"A 2- 4";
"Mode";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";"Voltage";
"Range";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";"10V";
"Comment";"Prove1";"Prove1";"Prove2";"Prove2";"Prove3";"Prove3";"Prove4";"Prove4";"Prove5";"Prove5";"Prove6";"Prove6";"Prove7";"Prove7";"Prove8";"Prove8";"Prove9";"Prove9";
"Scaling";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";"Off";
"Ratio";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";" 1.00000E+00";
"Offset";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";" 0.00000E+00";"-3.00000E+00";"-3.00000E+00";
"Time";"1-1[V]";"1-2[V]";"1-3[V]";"1-4[V]";"1-5[V]";"1-6[V]";"1-7[V]";"1-8[V]";"1-9[V]";"1-10[V]";"1-11[V]";"1-12[V]";"1-13[V]";"1-14[V]";"1-15[V]";"2-1[V]";"2-2[V]";"2-4[V]";"Event";
 0,000000000E+00; 8,69500E-01; 4,80350E+00; 3,76000E-01; 7,34950E+00; 5,60750E+00; 4,66450E+00; 8,31600E+00; 8,13950E+00; 6,66050E+00; 9,69700E+00; 1,81750E+00; 1,10900E+00; 6,82400E+00; 4,04900E+00; 9,82150E+00; 6,98000E+00; 2,94750E+00; 4,08750E+00;0;
 1,000000000E+01; 8,69500E-01; 4,80350E+00; 3,76000E-01; 7,34950E+00; 5,60750E+00; 4,66500E+00; 8,31600E+00; 8,13950E+00; 6,66050E+00; 9,69700E+00; 1,81700E+00; 1,10900E+00; 6,82400E+00; 4,04900E+00; 9,82150E+00; 6,98000E+00; 2,94750E+00; 4,08800E+00;0;
```

Each data set has a unique datetime value (`Trigger Time`) that is treated as a comment. Each data set also has a `Time` variable indicating the time that has passed since the datetime in `Trigger Time`. What I want to do is calculate the datetime for each observation so that I can graph the data as a time series using **R** Statistics. Is there a way to accomplish this? Merging the datasets and appending the comments does not necessarily have to be done in **R**.

I have imported the data from all files in **R** Statistics using the `list.files` and `llply` functions, [as suggested by Matt Bogard in this blog post](http://econometricsense.blogspot.no/2011/01/merging-multiple-data-frames-in-r.html). Here is a [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/616262/data-test.zip) to the data sets I use in the example below.

```
require(plyr)
filenames <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/bys/Desktop/log-trykk-vinkelrett/data-test/", full.names = TRUE)
import.list <- llply(filenames, read.csv)
```

Here is a [link the output from `import.list`](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/616262/importlist.txt) using `dput`.

I think I then need to do something similar to what [learnr is suggesting here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562124/merge-many-data-frames-from-csv-files), but so far my attempts at extracting `Trigger Time` and adding a new variable with `Trigger Time` for each observation have been unsuccessful.

Solving the problem with Open Refine causes the program to crash every time I try to load all the data sets. **R** may not be the best tool for processing text files, but I don't have any experience with Python, Ruby or similar languages.

Comment: If you've successfully imported the data, then it would be much better to give the structure of your data frames as opposed to that of the raw text.

Comment: I agree with @HongOoi provide us with a dataset by using the dput command or some other way for us to recreate the data.

Comment: Using `dput`I added the output from import.list (see code I added in edit)  to the file [importlist.txt](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/616262/importlist.txt). I also added a [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/616262/data-test.zip) to the data sets I use in the R code above.